# How to use form controls properties in a report?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, report

I'm trying to develop a simple database front-end for a school management system, I'm using a ReportViewer to display some data from a report, however I would like to display some data in the report that's not in the database, but in the UI as a user-input (think myTextBox.Text) ! How can this be done ?

Oh, and my ReportViewer is in a different Form than the user-input field i would like to use, I don't have a problem in having both Forms communicate together, but how to get data from one of the forms (control properties) into the report !

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, C#, database is an MS Access .accdb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution !
It's just a simple matter of using Report Parameters. It should be used as follows:

Suppose my main form (MyForm) contains a text box (myTextBox) that I would like to prints its value somewhere inside a report (myReport.rdlc, client-side report) which is shown on a ReportViewer component (myReportViewer).

The first thing that I want to do is add a Report Parameter to myReport. In the report designer, in the Report Data tab (leftmost panel) I click New > Parameter then I fill the detail of my parameter (Name, Type, Allow Null Values, Default Values...etc), lets say I named it paramText, with a type = Text.

Then in the Report Design surface, we set the expression of the field that's supposed to hold the data as follows :

```
=Parameters!paramText.Value
```

Now, back in our C# code, I just added the following code to my myFome_Load event to relate the text in myTextBox to the paramText :

```
myReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("paramText", myTextBox.Text));
```

That's it, this way the Text appearing in myTextBox will be shown somewhere you defined in the myReport ! This can be done for any WinForm control or property as long as you respect the typing of the property while you set the parameter.

If the ReportViewer is in another Form such as my case, I simply expose the Text property of myTextBox (accessing method) and use it in the other form.

PS. Make sure to include :

```
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you question correctly: you first take the user to a page with some input controls. When s/he enters a value and submits the form, you redirect the user to a Report page that will display the user input data along with other data pulled the database. If this is true, this my help you:

> You can pass information between pages in various ways, some of which
>   depend on how the redirection occurs. The following options are
>   available even if the source page is in a different ASP.NET Web
>   application from the target page, or if the source page is not an
>   ASP.NET Web Forms page:
>
> - Use a query string.
> - Get HTTP POST information from the source page.
>
>   The following options are available only when the source and target pages are in the same ASP.NET Web application.
>
>   - Use session state.
>   - Create public properties in the source page and    access the property values in the target page.
>   - Get control    information in the target page from controls in the source page.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx

EDIT: If working on a windows form, the following may help. I don't usually work with WinForms, so check out the source link for more detail:

Create a method on the receiving form to process the received data, like so:

```
internal void LoadCustomData(CustomClass customObject)  
{  
    // Update the local DataSet with the data in customObject     
}
```

Call this method on the input form and call the Show() method for the receiving form, like so:

```
private void customersDataGridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get data from the input control 
    CustomObject data;

    // Pass the data to receiving form
    ReceivingForm reportForm = new ReceivingForm();
    reportForm.LoadCustomData(data);
    reportForm.Show();
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you understood the problem, but, as I specified, I'm not seeking a solution to the "two forms communication" problem, i would like to get data from a form into a report ! and my application is a WinForms desktop app not a web app ! any other suggestion ?

Comment: Sadly, it still misses the point, you suggest that I update the database with data from the form control, but this isn't what i need to do. I need direct access to form controls in my report ! any other suggestion is welcome !

Comment: I am not suggesting update the database with the data. But you will likely need to update the data object that you get from the database with the new data obtained from the input. If that is not what you want to do, then you will have to pass two data structures to the second form, first, the one containing the data from the db and the second one (CustomObject) with the local data from the input. Both these data structures will be local data at this point and no transmission of data to the db takes place. Hope this clears things up a little bit.

Comment: I found a solution involving report parameters that i posted as an answer, thanks for the efforts.